# Facebook integration with azure function

Tags: c#, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I developed an Azure function and its running fine on Azure.

But I am finding it difficult to modify that function to set it up as a Facebook web hook so that my 'get()' and 'post()' methods get called with the required Facebook parameters.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your trials invested with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for webhook from facebook

```
namespace Facebook.Function
{
    public class AddLeadWebhook
    {    
        [FunctionName("AddLeadWebhook")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            this.log = log;
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Facebook challenge (facebook test webhook)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Query["hub.challenge"]))
            {
                log.LogInformation("Facebook challenged");
                return new OkObjectResult(req.Query["hub.challenge"].FirstOrDefault());
            }

            TODO process request
            ...

            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}
```